# why su command doesn't change the value of $USER variable in centos?

Tags: user-controls, operating-system, centos

I use centos v6.5 as os and i realize that value of $USER variable is not changed when i su with other user.
Is it a bug or my misunderstanding of su concept?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is duplicate of `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su`